# SQL to re-format email address

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I would like to put together SQL Select statement to reformat email addresses from the format `smith_john@test.com` to be formatted as `john.smith@test.com`. Obviously the number of characters in the first and last name are going to change, but the underscore character (_) will identify the addresses I am seeking to update.

What is the best way I can accomplish this? The email address field (`EMAIL_ADD`) currently contains the entire email address string.

Comment: a `charindex()` or two and then a few `substring()`s should do it.

Comment: Can you provide an example of that?

Comment: The documentation has loads of examples, @Nick. [SUBSTRING (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), [CHARINDEX (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've broken it out into its components so it's a bit easier to see.

```
declare @email varchar(100) = 'smith_john@test.com'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@email, CHARINDEX('_',@email )+1, CHARINDEX('@',@email )-CHARINDEX('_', @email)-1) --first name
       + '.'
       + LEFT(@email,CHARINDEX('_',@email )-1)  -- last name
       + RIGHT(@email, LEN(@email)- CHARINDEX('@', @email)+1)  --domain
```

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: One question - If I try to run this wide-open on my table, I get the error "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function."   Any ideas what to update? Not all of my Email addresses have underscores in them. Only some do.

Comment: Without knowing what's in the data, I can't say.  This query relies on there being one "_" and one "@" character in each value.  If either of those don't exist or there are more than one, you could potentially get this error.  You'll have to do some investigation of the data and add the appropriate error checking.

Comment: I wrapped it inside a `CASE` statement and that seems to be working :)

Answer (score 2):

Building on @WamLeslie's answer

`CROSS APPLY` helps a lot here because you can use the same expression multiple times

```sql
SELECT
   SUBSTRING(
       email,
       v1.underscore + 1,
       v2.atsign - v1.underscore - 1
   ) --first name
   + '.'
   + LEFT(email, v1.underscore - 1)  -- last name
   + RIGHT(email, LEN(email) - v2.atsign + 1)  --domain
FROM table
CROSS APPLY (VALUES( NULLIF(CHARINDEX('_', email), 0) )) AS v1(underscore)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES( NULLIF(CHARINDEX('@', email, v1.underscore), 0) )) AS v2(atsign)
```

Comment: CTEs can also be leveraged to reuse expressions via new names. That's how I do it. I don't know if it makes any difference, just mentioning as another option!

Comment: Yes you can use CTEs, but I find it far more cumbersome, as you keep having to re-declare the columns, `CROSS APPLY` keeps the same scope

Comment: In the above your have a field named `v2.underscore` and `v1.atsign` , these are not actual fields I have, so would I just fill these in with hard-coded values as `'_'` and `'@'`  ?

Comment: `CROSS APPLY` makes these calculations available as fields in the `SELECT` and in later joins and applys

Comment: I think I see what is going on, but should the 2nd `CROSS APPLY` statement have a underscore `'_'` in it, instead of the `@` symbol again?

Comment: Awesome thanks for the other option here!

Comment: I ran this and all I see to get is `NULL` values. Here is my code with with actual data: 
`SELECT
   SUBSTRING(
       EMAILID,
       v2.underscore + 1,
       v1.atsign - v2.underscore - 1
   ) --first name
   + '.'
   + LEFT(EMAILID, v2.underscore - 1)  -- last name
   + RIGHT(EMAILID, LEN(EMAILID) - v1.atsign + 1)  --domain
FROM PSUSEREMAIL
CROSS APPLY (VALUES( NULLIF(CHARINDEX('@',EMAILID), 0) )) AS v1(atsign)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES( NULLIF(CHARINDEX('_',EMAILID, v1.atsign), 0) )) AS v2(underscore)`

Comment: Looks like the calculationwas backwards, we need to get first the _ then @

Comment: Awesome works good to get format the email addresses with underscores in them. I'll have to wrap this in a conditional to get the other email addresses already properly formatted (i.e. firstname.lastname@test.com)